# Function doesn't wait for all the data before running, react and firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I am fetching from Firebase an object and a corresponding folder images, I then package them into one object that contains the links for all the images and return it, I then set it and render it. It won't render initially and only does when I save the overview folder.
I tried a bunch of random stuff so much so that I forgot, I have no idea what to do, I am new to react and firebase

Fetches data and passes it as a prop to overview

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Overview from "../../Components/DisplayOverview/Overview";
import { getJourney } from "../../Config/firestore";

export default function ExplorePage() {
  const [overviewInfo, setOverviewInfo] = useState([]);
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false)

useEffect(() => {
  const plonk = async () => {
    setOverviewInfo(await getJourney())
  }
  plonk()
  console.log(overviewInfo)
},[])
  return <div className="explore-cont">
    {
    overviewInfo.map((x) =>
    <Overview
          key={crypto.randomUUID()}
          im={x.imageURL}
          name={x.name}
          location={x.location}
          description={x.description}
          photoURL={x.photoURL}
          userName={x.userName}
          price={x.price}
        ></Overview>)
        }
        </div>;
}
```

Takes the renders component(overview file)

```
import React, { Component, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "react-responsive-carousel/lib/styles/carousel.min.css"; // requires a loader
import { Carousel } from "react-responsive-carousel";
import "./overview.css";

export default function Overview(props) {
  const [iamges, setImages] = useState([])

  useEffect(()=>{

    setImages(props.im)
  
  },[props])


  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="image-cont">
        <Carousel
          autoPlay={true}
          infiniteLoop={true}
          showThumbs={false}
          showIndicators={false}
          showStatus={false}
          width={200}
          useKeyboardArrows={false}
          centerMode={true}
          autoFocus={false}
        >
          {iamges.map(a=> {
            return(
              <div key={crypto.randomUUID()}>
                <img src={a} />
              </div>
            )
          })}
        </Carousel>
      </div>
      <div className="words-cont">
        <span className="otitle">{props.name}</span>
        <span className="location">{props.location}</span>
        <span className="description">{props.description}</span>
        <div className="person-info">
          <img className="image" src={props.photoURL} />
          <span className="username">{props.userName}</span>
          <span className="price">£{props.price}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Fetches data from firebase

```
import { addDoc, collection, getDocs  } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from './firebase'
import { ref } from "firebase/storage";
import { retrieveImages } from "./storage";

//path for fireStore
const JOURNEYDATA = `journeyData`

export async function addJourneyData(uid,location,name,description,price, uuid, username,photoURL){
    //add a document to the collection in db with the path of JOURNEYDATA, with an object
    const myDocRef = addDoc(collection(db,JOURNEYDATA), {uid: uid,
        name: name,
        location: location,
        description: description,
        price: price,
        imageBucket: `/JourneyImages/${uid}/${uuid}/overview`,
        userName: username,
        photoURL: photoURL
    })
         
        return myDocRef 
} 


export async function addActivityData(activityName, description, price, imageBucket , docRef,n){
    
    addDoc(collection(db,`${docRef.path}/acivity`),{
        activityNumber: n,
        activityName: activityName,
        description: description,
        price: price,
        imageBucket: imageBucket
    })
}

//fetch data
export async function getJourney(){
    const querySnapshot = getDocs(collection(db,JOURNEYDATA))

    let allData = []

    for(const documentSnapshot of (await querySnapshot).docs){
        const data = documentSnapshot.data()
        await allData.push({
            ...data,
            id: documentSnapshot.id,
            imageURL: await retrieveImages(data['imageBucket'])
        })
    }
    return allData

}
```

fetches image from firestore

```
import { ref, uploadBytes, getDownloadURL, listAll } from "firebase/storage"
import { storage } from './firebase'



export async function uploadImages(images, uid, projectName, overview){
    //allows multiple files to be sent
    for(let i = 0; i < images.length; i++){
        let bucket = `/JourneyImages/${uid}/${projectName}/${overview}/${images[i].name}`
        const imageRef = ref(storage, bucket)
        const result = await uploadBytes(imageRef, images[i]).then(console.log('success')).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
        })
    }
}

export async function retrieveImages(bucket){
    let imageList = []
    await listAll(ref(storage, bucket)).then((res) => res.items.forEach(element => {
    getDownloadURL(ref(storage , element.fullPath)).then(url => {
        imageList.push(url)
    })
   }))
   return imageList
}
```

[initial render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDrh6.png) 
[after saving the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUY4S.png)

Comment: the `getDownloadURL` in the `.forEach` is running asynchronously and you are not waiting for that at all

Comment: change the function to `export async function retrieveImages(bucket) { const res = await listAll(ref(storage, bucket)); return Promise.all(res.items.map(element => getDownloadURL(ref(storage, element.fullPath)))); }`